# how to highlight text in textarea in angular?

Tags: angular, textarea, form-control

i have textarea form and want when i type more than specific number of character in it (more than 2200 character), all text after this get highlighted.

this is my html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <textarea type="text"
                    id="textAreaScroll"
                    formControlName="text"
                    placeholder="متن ..."
                    (keyup)="postLengthCheck('text')">
          </textarea>
</div>
```

and this is my typescript code:

```
postLengthCheck(input) {
    if (input === 'text') {
      if (this.createPostForm.controls['text'].value !== null) {
        this.postLength = this.createPostForm.controls['text'].value.length;
        this.validTextLength = 2200 - this.postLength;
        if (this.postLength > 2200) {
          this.x = this.createPostForm.controls['text'].value.substring(2200, this.postLength);
          console.log(this.x);
          this.match = new RegExp(this.x, 'ig');
          this.markText = '<mark>' + this.x + '<\/mark>';
          this.replaced = this.createPostForm.controls['text'].value.replace(this.match, this.markText);
          this.createPostForm.controls['text'].value = this.replaced;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

and in my `css` i define `mark` class like below:

```
mark {
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: #b1d5e5;
}
```

but this not worked. how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do not create your own HTML tags, use something like `<span class="highlighted-text">the text</span>` instead.

Also, a `textarea` only contains text (not HTML) so you have to change it to a `<div contenteditable="true">the text</div>`, that's how every HTML WYSIWYG editor works.

Comment: how can i set formcontrol with use div ??

Comment: I suggest you create your own formcontrol by implementing `ControlValueAccessor`. Indeed, Angular does not provide an implementation for it as it would be too much opinionated.

Comment: how can i do this with ControlValueAccessor ?

Comment: Embed your `div contenteditable="true"` in a component, then make your component implement `ControlValueAccessor`, then write the implementation of the functions. After that, you'll be able to use the component as a formcontrol.

Comment: i create ControlValueAccessor , now how i can apply <span class="highlighted-text">the text</span> to desired part ?

Comment: Well it shouldn't be very different from what you did before, now I'm sorry but if you have troubles at this point, you should open a new question because your original question has already been answered. If you do so, I'd be pleased to help you again.